# jTextField validation for numbers and one decimal point?

Tags: java, swing, validation, decimal, jtextfield

I need to set a jTextField to accept only numbers and one decimal point.Nothing else. Decimal point can't be typed more than once and no other characters are allowed. How can I do this?

I typed this code. but it doesn't work well. I mean it accept Strings until i type a decimal point

```
    if (!Character.isDigit(evt.getKeyChar()) & crqty.getText().indexOf(".") != -1) {
        evt.consume();
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You appear to be using a `KeyListener` to manage `KeyEvents in the`JTextField. This is not a suitable for filtering the document of this `JTextComponent`.  Here you could use a `JFormattedTextField` combined with a `MaskFormatter` to accept a maximum 8 digits separated by a decimal point.

```
JFormattedTextField textField = new JFormattedTextField();
MaskFormatter dateMask = new MaskFormatter("####.####");
dateMask.install(textField);
```

For a more free-format input (e.g. more digits) you could use a `DocumentFilter` with a `JTextField`. Here is an integer filter [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11093326/restricting-jtextfield-input-to-integers)

Comment: I'm new to java. Could you please explain this more? I mean where should I type this code?

Comment: You can either completely replace your `JTextField` with a fixed input `JFormattedTextField` or use a `DocumentFilter` with a `JTextField` similar to that shown in the example :)

Answer (score 3):

Very good question! I downloaded this code (I can't remember which site it was) a long time ago which allows you to enter only a numbers:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class JNumericField extends JTextField {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final char DOT = '.';
    private static final char NEGATIVE = '-';
    private static final String BLANK = "";
    private static final int DEF_PRECISION = 2;

    public static final int NUMERIC = 2;
    public static final int DECIMAL = 3;

    public static final String FM_NUMERIC = "0123456789";
    public static final String FM_DECIMAL = FM_NUMERIC + DOT; 

    private int maxLength = 0;
    private int format = NUMERIC;
    private String negativeChars = BLANK;
    private String allowedChars = null;
    private boolean allowNegative = false;
    private int precision = 0;

    protected PlainDocument numberFieldFilter;

    public JNumericField() {

        this(2, DECIMAL);
    }

    public JNumericField(int iMaxLen) {
        this(iMaxLen, NUMERIC);
    }

    public JNumericField(int iMaxLen, int iFormat) {
        setAllowNegative(true);
        setMaxLength(iMaxLen);
        setFormat(iFormat);

        numberFieldFilter = new JNumberFieldFilter();
        super.setDocument(numberFieldFilter);
    }

    public void setMaxLength(int maxLen) {
        if (maxLen > 0)
            maxLength = maxLen;
        else
            maxLength = 0;
    }

    public int getMaxLength() {
        return maxLength;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enable) {
        super.setEnabled(enable);

        if (enable) {
            setBackground(Color.white);
            setForeground(Color.black);
        } else {
            setBackground(Color.lightGray);
            setForeground(Color.darkGray);
        }
    }

    public void setEditable(boolean enable) {
        super.setEditable(enable);

        if (enable) {
            setBackground(Color.white);
            setForeground(Color.black);
        } else {
            setBackground(Color.lightGray);
            setForeground(Color.darkGray);
        }
    }

    public void setPrecision(int iPrecision) {
        if (format == NUMERIC)
            return;

        if (iPrecision >= 0)
            precision = iPrecision;
        else
            precision = DEF_PRECISION;
    }

    public int getPrecision() {
        return precision;
    }

    public Number getNumber() {
        Number number = null;
        if (format == NUMERIC)
            number = new Integer(getText());
        else
            number = new Double(getText());

        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(Number value) {
        setText(String.valueOf(value));
    }

    public int getInt() {
        return Integer.parseInt(getText());
    }

    public void setInt(int value) {
        setText(String.valueOf(value));
    }

    public float getFloat() {
        return (new Float(getText())).floatValue();
    }

    public void setFloat(float value) {
        setText(String.valueOf(value));
    }

    public double getDouble() {
        return (new Double(getText())).doubleValue();
    }

    public void setDouble(double value) {
        setText(String.valueOf(value));
    }

    public int getFormat() {
        return format;
    }

    public void setFormat(int iFormat) {
        switch (iFormat) {
        case NUMERIC:
        default:
            format = NUMERIC;
            precision = 0;
            allowedChars = FM_NUMERIC;
            break;

        case DECIMAL:
            format = DECIMAL;
            precision = DEF_PRECISION;
            allowedChars = FM_DECIMAL;
            break;
        }
    }

    public void setAllowNegative(boolean b) {
        allowNegative = b;

        if (b)
            negativeChars = "" + NEGATIVE;
        else
            negativeChars = BLANK;
    }

    public boolean isAllowNegative() {
        return allowNegative;
    }

    public void setDocument(Document document) {
    }

    class JNumberFieldFilter extends PlainDocument {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public JNumberFieldFilter() {
            super();
        }

        public void insertString(int offset, String str, AttributeSet attr)
                throws BadLocationException {
            String text = getText(0, offset) + str
                    + getText(offset, (getLength() - offset));

            if (str == null || text == null)
                return;

            for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
                if ((allowedChars + negativeChars).indexOf(str.charAt(i)) == -1)
                    return;
            }

            int precisionLength = 0, dotLength = 0, minusLength = 0;
            int textLength = text.length();

            try {
                if (format == NUMERIC) {
                    if (!((text.equals(negativeChars)) && (text.length() == 1)))
                        new Long(text);
                } else if (format == DECIMAL) {
                    if (!((text.equals(negativeChars)) && (text.length() == 1))) 
                        new Double(text);

                    int dotIndex = text.indexOf(DOT);
                    if (dotIndex != -1) {
                        dotLength = 1;
                        precisionLength = textLength - dotIndex - dotLength;

                        if (precisionLength > precision)
                            return;
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                return;
            }

            if (text.startsWith("" + NEGATIVE)) {
                if (!allowNegative)
                    return;
                else
                    minusLength = 1;
            }

            if (maxLength < (textLength - dotLength - precisionLength - minusLength))
                return;

            super.insertString(offset, str, attr);
        }
    }
}
```

You will use it in this way:

```
JNumericField numField = new JNumericField();

numField.setMaxLength(10); //Set maximum length             
numField.setPrecision(1); //Set precision (1 in your case)              
numField.setAllowNegative(true); //Set false to disable negatives
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do simple validation for your JTextField....

```
JTextField.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
  public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {

    char text[];
        int count = 0; 
        text = JTextField.getText().toCharArray();
        for(int i = 0 ; i< text.length ; i++){
            if(text[i] == '.'){
                count++;
            }
        }
        if(count>=1 && evt.getKeyChar() == '.'){
            evt.consume();
        }

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   if(!Character.isDigit(evt.getKeyChar())&&evt.getKeyChar()!='.'){
       evt.consume();
   } 
   if(evt.getKeyChar()=='.'&&jTextField1.getText().contains(".")){
      evt.consume();
       }
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. However, it would be better if you added some explanations, not just code.

Answer (score -1):

```
char c=evt.getKeyChar();
if(!(Character.isDigit(c)||
    (c==KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE)||c==KeyEvent.VK_DELETE||evt.getKeyChar() == '.')){
//  evt.getKeyChar() == '.' does accept point when jtextfield accepts decimal number
  evt.consume();
  getToolkit().beep();
}
```