# Setting up JTextField Settings

Tags: java, swing, numbers, jtextfield, documentfilter

I've got a `JTextField`.  Is there any way I can restrict it to only allow the user to insert numbers in to it?

Currently I've got a button connected to the Text Field so when its pressed it does `getText()` and converts it to a `int`, obviously this becomes a problem if the user does not submit an `int` in the first place.

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14215847/jtextfield-validation-for-numbers-and-one-decimal-point/14219756#14219756

Comment: Or a `JFormattedTextField` as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13424140/1076463)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [DocumentFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html), it is effective in your case. Here is the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) to implement it.

Comment: A `JSpinner` would be better for getting an `int` value.

Answer (score 2):

```
  try {
     int x = Integer.parseInt(input);
     isInt = true;
 }
  catch(NumberFormatException nFE) {
     isInt=false;
 }
```

You could validate the button input if `isInt` is `true`. Hope it helps!

Comment: This is totally my bad. Didn't understand the question correctly. Answer edited.

Comment: done! no worries, I guess I should read questions twice.

Comment: *"I guess I should read questions twice"*  And I should be more careful in my reading of comments and edited answers.  ;)  +1

Comment: thanks Andrew, although your approach is more appropiate for this issue. +1 on your comments. Gosh this seems a love history. Where's the pony and the rainbow??

Comment: *"Where's the pony and the rainbow"*  The pony is playing the violins you hear, the rainbow .. I'm not sure, but it's night where I am.  :)