# Common method for the JTextFields to accept only numbers

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, keylistener, documentfilter

I limit my `JTextFields` to accept only numbers. I was using following code for this.

```
  // my textboxes
  t1=new JTextField(10);
  t2=new JTextField(10);
  t3=new JTextField(10);

  // for the first one
  t1.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
          char c = e.getKeyChar();
          if (!((c >= '0') && (c <= '9') ||
             (c == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) ||
             (c == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE))) {
            getToolkit().beep();
            e.consume();
          }
        }
      });
```

Suppose I have 20 `texboxes` which need the same validation check. So do we need to write this code 20 times? Can I write a common method to implement this? I am new to `Swing`.

Comment: Don't use a KeyListener whatever you do, since that has no effect on copy/paste and can mess up the JTextField in other ways. Use a DocumentFilter. You can find examples of this on this site and in the tutorials. For example: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9346426/522444).

Comment: Have a look at this question, it should solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14215847/jtextfield-validation-for-numbers-and-one-decimal-point/14219756#14219756 More precisely, my answer. Thats a custom made component which accepts only number.

Comment: You are getting a ton of the wrong answer. Pitiful.

Comment: yes we GET IT. There is a better way of filtering a JTextfield, using DOcumentFilter. But that is not the main point of his question. His question is about RE-USE

Comment: @OliverWatkins: it is ***BAD*** advice. Please knock it off. The point is we should not mislead newbies because we're supposed to know better.

Comment: @OliverWatkins Read question again.

Comment: Use a `JSpinner` as seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10021773/418556).

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13424140/1076463)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any way to accept only numeric values in a JTextField?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313390/is-there-any-way-to-accept-only-numeric-values-in-a-jtextfield)

Comment: @Robin : I was asking for the solution to a specific issue I faced while playing with the above code. I don't think it is a duplication

Comment: @OliverWatkins So what is the difference between creating a single `DocumentFilter` or a single `KeyListener`?  Both are reusable, only the `DocumentFilter` was built for the task at hand.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting JTextField "deselect" event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14305921/detecting-jtextfield-deselect-event)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Again, use a DocumentFilter as this will handle copy and paste, this will allow filtering *before* the Document accepts the text:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class DocListenerEg extends JPanel {
   private static final int FIELD_COUNT = 5;
   private JTextField[] fields = new JTextField[FIELD_COUNT];

   public DocListenerEg() {
      MyDocFilter myFilter = new MyDocFilter();
      for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
         fields[i] = new JTextField(5);
         ((PlainDocument) fields[i].getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(myFilter);
         add(fields[i]);
      }
   }

   private class MyDocFilter extends DocumentFilter {
      public void insertString(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset,
            String text, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
         for (char c : text.toCharArray()) {
            if (!Character.isDigit(c)) {
               return;
            }
         }
         fb.insertString(offset, text.toUpperCase(), attr);
      }

      public void replace(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset,
            int length, String text, AttributeSet attrs)
            throws BadLocationException {
         for (char c : text.toCharArray()) {
            if (!Character.isDigit(c)) {
               return;
            }
         }
         fb.replace(offset, length, text.toUpperCase(), attrs);
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      DocListenerEg mainPanel = new DocListenerEg();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("DocListenerEg");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: +1.. @log_in see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14305921/detecting-jtextfield-deselect-event/14305952#14305952) too (shows other ways like `InputVerfier` and `JFormattedTextField`)

Answer (score 4):

Try DocumentFilter as described in http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter

Answer (score 0):

Save your anonymus class into a variable:

```
KeyListener keyListener= new KeyAdapter() {
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
      char c = e.getKeyChar();
      if (!((c >= '0') && (c <= '9') ||
         (c == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) ||
         (c == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE))) {
        getToolkit().beep();
        e.consume();
      }
    }
  }
```

And then

```
t1.addKeyListener(keyListener);
t2.addKeyListener(keyListener);
t3.addKeyListener(keyListener);
...
```

Comment: Again, never use a KeyListener for this.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Why not to use a KeyListener? It works.

Comment: @SriHarshaChilakapati: It won't for copy and paste! Again, knock this off please.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Then please say which works for copy and paste also.

Comment: @SriHarshaChilakapati: I already have -- see comments to main question.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels where does it say he needs to be able to copy and paste from textfields?

Comment: @OliverWatkins: so you're saying that it is better to hamper a JTextFields abilities just so you can use a faulty technique? The key is to use the *best* tool for the job.

Comment: *"where does it say he needs to be able to copy and paste from textfields?"* - Will be the next question the OP asks because they were given the wrong advice.  You can not guarantee the order that `KeyListener` will be notified, by the type it reaches your handler, the field could already be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class called :

**NumberOnlyTextField**

Make it extend **JTextField**, and add the **addKeyListener**(..) code in the constructor. There you have your very own number validation textfield.

Comment: Again, never use a KeyListener for this. Please don't recommend this. Don't mislead newbies.

Comment: There may be a better way for filtering the text field out there. But thats not the point of his question. He wanted to know how to apply reuse in his code.

Comment: Nevertheless, it's a bad practice.

Comment: This is not another way to do this. This is a ***wrong*** way to do this. Cut this out please.

Comment: its a perfectly fine way of doing it. I have used this technique many many times before. Why the hell should i cut this out?

Comment: Try copy and paste with your "perfectly fine" technique. Then try it with mine.

Comment: There is no guarantee in the order `KeyListener` is notified.  By the time your listener is notified the fields document may have already begin updated.

Answer (score 0):

I would make a private boolean method (if it is only used in this class) or public if it it called for elsewhere as well eg. using reg ex:

```
public boolean checkToBeNumberInput(char c, KeyEvent e){
 if(!char c.matches("[0-9]")||
   (c == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) ||
   (c == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE))) {
   getToolkit().beep();
   e.consume();
   return false;

 }
return true;
}
```

Then call for this boolean method and if it returns true:

```
if(checkToBeNumberInput()==false){
System.out.println("only numbers are allowed!");
}
```

This is a fast draft but I hope it helps someone

Answer (score 0):

//look event keypressed
.
:
private void montoingresoKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) 
{

```
    if(Character.isLetter(evt.getKeyChar()))
    {
        //do what you want on this event, when key is pressed named evt
    }
```

}