# How do I prevent entering '.' character in JFormattedTextField

Tags: java, swing, validation, jtextfield, jformattedtextfield

How do I prevent entering '.' character in JFormattedTextField (or JTextField if that easier) ?

Comment: For a JTextField, you could use a DocumentFilter, and there are many examples of this on this site (some written by me). For a JFormattedTextField, write a formatter that doesn't allow '.'. Surely you've checked out the tutorials for this class, right? If so, what have you tried and how is it now working?

Comment: Don't use a KeyListener for this as this won't work with copy and paste as well as has other problems. An example of a DocumentFilter solution can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11093360).

Comment: So which is the best solution DocumentFilter with JTextField, or Mask with JFormattedTextField - Im unclear how to code a DocumentFilter to do what I want.

Comment: either can work fine. For an example of a DocumentFilter, please see the link that I have provided in my link above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also write a simple listener:

<strike>addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
     public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
         if(e.getKeyChar() == '.') {
            e.consume();
         }
    }
});</strike>

---

**Edit**:

As @HovercraftFullOfEels mentioned in the comments, you better use [DocumentFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html), see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17294519/common-method-for-the-jtextfields-to-accept-only-numbers/17294808#17294808) for a good explanation and refer for [the tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter).

**Edit 2**:
You can try to [MaskFormatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/MaskFormatter.html):

```
MaskFormatter formatter = new MaskFormatter(/*Check out the link*/);
JFormattedTextField tf = new JFormattedTextField(formatter );
```

Comment: I did look at maskFormatter but i didn't really have a format mask so dismissed it, i just wanted to ignore one char, but found setInvalidCharacters() which should do

Comment: This is not a good answer -1. KeyListeners need to be avoided in such situation as has been discussed *many* times on this and other sites. For one this solution will not work with copy and paste, a basic text component functionality. I've already mentioned a much better solution in my initial comment, a DocumentFilter.

Comment: I've re-added your JFormattedTextField info as it too is valid. Thanks.