# check if a long type contains characters

Tags: java

I have a textfield which takes long value and if it takes characters then it should display an error message. Is there any method like isNAN() for long to check whether that variable contains any character?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) There are many possible solutions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Restricting JTextField input to Integers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11093326/restricting-jtextfield-input-to-integers)

Comment: I tried using try/catch. but is there any method like isNAN() to check whether the variable is a number or not

Comment: @justified : care to accept any of the answer?

Answer (score 1):

The static method [`Long.parseLong()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong%28java.lang.String%29) will throw a `NumberFormatException` if the string does not contain a parsable long.

Comment: Or even better, prevent the user from entering a non number character with a filter.

Comment: @justified.. Then catch the exception, and print the message from the properties file there.

Answer (score 1):

You can usually do this by trying to do `Long.parseLong(textfield.getText())` wrapped by a `try` `catch` block where you would catch the `NumberFormatException`.

If the exception is caught then it means the user didn't enter a valid `long` value.

Answer (score 1):

long x = Long.parseLong("12345L");

You should try catch the above statement as it can throw NumberFormatException

Answer (score 1):

You can have a small utility method like this:

```
private boolean isLong(String str){
    try{
      Long.parseLong(str);
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
      return false;
    }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as an alternative to other solutions, you can use a regex

```
    boolean containsCharacters = !txt.matches("-?\\d+");
```