# How to be sure about Integer value of a JTextfield?

Tags: java, swing, integer, jtextfield, parseint

I have a JTextField which users **must** enter a **number** in that.

***I want to check the value to be sure that it contains an ***Integer***.***

Here is the code:

```
JTextField Tex_amount=new JTextField();
.
.
.
String s=Tex_amount.getText(); 
int a=Integer.parseInt(s);
```

The problem is if the user enter a String in the field i will face with the error:
**java.lang.NumberFormatException**. So how can i check the value?

Comment: do some validation where user can allowed only numeric from the keyboard.

Comment: Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11093326/restricting-jtextfield-input-to-integers for restricting input to only integers

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/13424140/1076463

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use try..catch

```
try{
    int a = Integer.parseInt(s);
}
catch(ArithmeticException e){
    //Handel error here 
}
```

Answer (score 7):

there are three ways

1. use JFormattedTextField with Number Formatter
2. use JSpinner with SpinnerNumberModel
3. add DocumentFilter to plain JTextField