# how do I change a user input string (jtextfield) into an int variable?

Tags: java, swing, awt, jtextfield

I am doing my first java program with a GUI. I need to change the input from the user entered into a jTextField to a int variable i can use for work.

Comment: String var = val.getText();

Comment: A better choice would be to use a field designed for the work like a `JSpinner` or `JFormattedField`...

Answer (score 0):

Get the text and use Integer.parseInt(your String here);

Comment: int quarters = Integer.parseInt(jTextField); i get a syntax error on jTextField

Comment: You need to retrieve the String first. Try jTextField.getText()

Answer (score 0):

```
int a = Integer.parseInt(jtextfield.getText());
// `jtextfield` will be your `JTextField` object
```

Comment: int quarters = Integer.parseInt(jtextfield.getText());

Comment: @sobey what is your `JTextField` object name?

Answer (score 0):

```
    JTextField jTextField=new JTextField(); // initialize textFild
    String str=jTextField.getText(); // get text value
```

Now you can convert this into int value.

```
    int val=Integer.parseInt(jTextField.getText());
```

Answer (score 0):

`jtextfield.gettext()` will return the entered String..
we can parse this string into integer

```
integer.parseInt(txtfield.getText());
```

but if we are typing values other than numbers `0-9` in the text filed it show `java.lang.NumberFormatException`

only numbers can be parsed into the integer

```
int num=Integer.parseInt("2")// is correct

int num=Integer.parseInt("two")//this will give numberformat exception
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int result = Integer.parseInt(jTextField.getText());
```

and apply

```
class MyIntFilter extends DocumentFilter {
   @Override
   public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offset, String string,
         AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {

      Document doc = fb.getDocument();
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      sb.append(doc.getText(0, doc.getLength()));
      sb.insert(offset, string);

      if (test(sb.toString())) {
         super.insertString(fb, offset, string, attr);
      } else {
         // warn the user and don't allow the insert
      }
   }

   private boolean test(String text) {
      try {
         Integer.parseInt(text);
         return true;
      } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
         return false;
      }
   }

   @Override
   public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text,
         AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {

      Document doc = fb.getDocument();
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      sb.append(doc.getText(0, doc.getLength()));
      sb.replace(offset, offset + length, text);

      if (test(sb.toString())) {
         super.replace(fb, offset, length, text, attrs);
      } else {
         // warn the user and don't allow the insert
      }

   }

   @Override
   public void remove(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length)
         throws BadLocationException {
      Document doc = fb.getDocument();
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      sb.append(doc.getText(0, doc.getLength()));
      sb.delete(offset, offset + length);

      if (test(sb.toString())) {
         super.remove(fb, offset, length);
      } else {
         // warn the user and don't allow the insert
      }

   }
}
```

(This class copied from [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11093326/restricting-jtextfield-input-to-integers#answer-11093360))

```
PlainDocument doc = (PlainDocument) jTextField.getDocument();
doc.setDocumentFilter(new MyIntFilter());
```

This way you can restrict your input to numbers and get the string to integer by parsing it