# Java - Use a DocumentFilter to limit allowed characters and length

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, documentfilter

Is it possible to use a single `DocumentFilter` to limit both the allowed characters and the number of characters in a `JTextField`?
I don't get how to do both and I didn't find any fully working workaround.

Comment: Yes, see [How To limit the number of characters in JTextField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519151/how-to-limit-the-number-of-characters-in-jtextfield) and combine it with this answer: [Allow only numbers in JTextfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541230/allow-only-numbers-in-jtextfield) just change it to work with the character types you want.

Comment: The first question is solved using setDocument() with a PlainDocument, the second one actually uses a DocumentFilter. Anyway, I tried to set both the document using JTextField#setDocument and the document filter through setDocumentFilter() on the AbstractDocument obtained from JTextField#getDocument, but the second instruction I wrote overwrites the first one. In other words, I cannot set both a PlainDocument and a DocumentFilter this way.

Comment: You need to combine both answers into a single document and set it once. A PlainDocument is a Subclasses of AbstractDocument, so in the first example that extends a PlainDocument you can also override the replace method and any other methods of the Abstract/PlainDocument as shown here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11093326/restricting-jtextfield-input-to-integers Or you can just override an AbstractDocument and implement the limit in there instead. And when you set the document you only need to sit it once for example `yourTextField.setDocument(new yourCustomDocument(textLimit));`

Comment: @sorifiend That's what I was trying to do, but I cannot grasp how to correctly override that method. My only result for now is a `JTextField` that doubles any inserted valid character, lets write once the banned ones and is able to exceed the text limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I finally get how it works! I needed to use `if`s in `replace()` method, because that's the code that gets called everytime the user inputs/pastes anything in the `JTextField`:

1. if the already inserted text length (`fb.getDocument().getLength()`) summed to the user current input/paste (`text.length()`) is greater than the intended limit (I setted it to 12 characters), first delete any invalid characters from the user input (`text.replaceAll(regex, "")`) and then truncate it so that it does not exceed the limit;
2. otherwise, if the text would not exceed the limit, just delete any possible invalid characters.

```
class NameFilter extends DocumentFilter {
    @Override
    public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text, AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {
        int finalLength = fb.getDocument().getLength() + text.length();

        if(finalLength > 12) {
            fb.replace(offset, length, text.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9/&\\-':;.,?!@]", "").substring(0, 12-fb.getDocument().getLength()), attrs);
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        } else
            fb.replace(offset, length, text.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9/&\\-':;.,?!@]", ""), attrs);
    }
}
```

Comment: @kleopatra I was just editing the answer. Now that should be just the right solution I was looking for!

Comment: glad you found a solution with Documentfilter :)