# How do I properly read numbers from awt textfields?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I've written a GUI for a simulation project that I'm doing, and in the event handling code of the window, I have, for instance,

```
private void timestepKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
    String text = timestep.getText();
    AMEC.steptime = Integer.parseInt(text);
}
```

where I would like to assign any input typed into field timestep to be assigned to AMEC.steptime. I do this for all textfields.

However, my simulation doesn't run properly when passed these parameters, and upon debugging I found that only the first character gets parsed to int. For instance, if I type "31", then the value assigned to AMEC.steptime becomes 3 instead of 31.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that you are using a `KeyListener`.  Just don't use it, use an `ActionListener` and when you hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd> `actionPerformed` is executed. Then you can put the same code an will run like a charm.

Use swing not awt.

Example how to use it:

import first:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
```

Then in somewhere in your code

```
JTextField textfield = new JTextField();
        textfield.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JTextField timestep =(JTextField) e.getSource();// you could use this or just your variable.
                String text = timestep.getText();
                AMEC.steptime = Integer.parseInt(text);
            }

        });
```

As a side note, you would be interested in only allowing in this textfield number values. Read more in how to make it in this previous question.
[Restricting JTextField input to Integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11093326/restricting-jtextfield-input-to-integers)

Comment: Sorry, I didnt' remove the KeyListener function before adding the ActionListener. Thanks, this worked!

Comment: @Martin ok, i put it an example

Comment: @nachokk: it was just a duplicate of yours.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels but it was at the same time, no copyright involved xD , you should not delete it

Comment: Well, I read both, and yours was cleaner than mine. And I don't need the up-votes, so why muddy the waters?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels alright xD now i linked an answer of you, now is shared :)