# JOptionPane InputMismatchException

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

i am building a simple chat application and i'm thinking to set the server address and port through JOptionPane, what i want to do is to check that the user is not entering letters in when setting up the port number,

```
int port=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please insert the default port!");
```

i tried to handle it with a try/catch block but it didn't worked, any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by "i tried to handle it with a try/catch block but it didn't work"?

Comment: `try{code}catch(inputmismatchexception){}` @BackSlash

Comment: And what didn't work?

Comment: it showed an error, however i just fixed it, thanks anyway :) instead of inputmismatchexception it needs numberformat exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NumberFormatException is apparently the answer, so now this question will not show up as unanswered.

```
try{
    int port=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please insert the default port!");
}catch(NumberFormatException e){
   //handle error
}
```

Comment: you know of any way to make the JOptionPane show up until you put the right result?, i mean if you put a letter, prompt an error message and than reenter the input again?

Comment: I have used DocumentFilter for this. It works very well. Here is a link to an example:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11093326/restricting-jtextfield-input-to-integers