# Java: How to convert JTextArea text to bits String

Tags: java

Want to convert JtextArea text to bits String.

I'm using two JTextArea one for input and one for output and one button which is executing following code:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

int ssc =Integer.parseInt(jta1.getText());
                        String sc=Integer.toBinaryString(ssc);
                        char[] bc=sc.toCharArray();
                        for (char c : bc) {
                        sb.append("-");


int i =Character.getNumericValue(c);
                    String a = String.valueOf(i);
                    sb.append(a.toString());
                    jta2.setText(a);
Error           

    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "dsa"
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:449)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:499)
        at MainFrame$2.actionPerformed(MainFrame.java:57)
```

Comment: Where is the issue? Can you explain it a bit more?

Comment: This is the error im getting when i click button              Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "dsa"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:449)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:499)
 at MainFrame$2.actionPerformed(MainFrame.java:57)

Comment: Its clear from the exception that it is converting a string into integer.

Comment: Read it here [Restricting JTextField input to Integers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11093326/restricting-jtextfield-input-to-integers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Integer.parseInt(jta1.getText());`

Assuming you are trying to parse more than just numbers, the above is causing the `NumberFormatException`. the parser can only parse number strings like "1234", not letters `"dsa"`.

`java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "dsa"`

What you *can* do is iterate through the characters and just cast each to an int and append the binary string of each character

```
for (char c : txt.toCharArrray() ) {
    String binaryOfCharacter = Integer.toBinaryString((int)c);
    // append to StringBuilder
}
```

<sub>**Note:** each character only returns the seven bit repsresentation</sub>