# How can I limit JTextField to numbers, or prvent the damage of letters?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I am using a two dimensional array of JTextFields to take in x y points, and graph them on a JPanel.

What is the best way to either limit the input to numbers, or prevent letter from blowing up my program?

Here is a snippet of code, that does not like when an letter is entered.

```
Float smallX = Float.parseFloat(xyInput[0][0].getText());
            for (Integer i = 0; i < xyInput.length; i++) {
                String number = xyInput[i][0].getText();
                Float testX = Float.parseFloat(number);

                if (smallX > testX) {
                    smallX = testX;
                    System.out.println("smallX = " + smallX);
                }
            }
```

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: [For example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11093360/522444)

Answer (score 1):

- `JFormattedTextField` - post validation; see [How to Use Formatted Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html)
- `JSpinner` - post validation; see [How to Use Spinners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html)
- `InputVerifer` - post validation; see [Validating Input](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#inputVerification)
- `DocumentFilter` - real time validation; see [Implementing a Document Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) and [DocumentFilter Examples](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter)