# How to input integer number in Swing?

Tags: java, swing, integer, jtextfield, jformattedtextfield

I have code

```
    NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance();
    format.setGroupingUsed(false);

    JFormattedTextField jtf = new JFormattedTextField(format);

    jtf.setValue(new Integer(0));
    jtf.setColumns(10);
```

but when I input characters in text field they stay printed until i switch to another text field. I need to forbid characters input totally, i mean when character is inputted i need to delete at the moment or make somehow for character to not even appear for processing by listener if that is possible and also not to appear in text field ofcourse. I mean only characters which are digits must appear.

Comment: Why are you defining a second `JFormattedTextField` called `jtf` there?

Comment: You probably would need to register a key press listener that checks if this field is selected, and if it is, ignores key presses for invalid characters.

Comment: Because it is better than nothing for inputting integers. it deletes characters which are not numbers after selecting next jtf(after jtf unfocused/unselected letters inputted disappear from input).

Comment: What?  I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: Sorry, fixed. Now i understand what you've meant.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in possible duplicates for that question 
[Restricting JTextField input to Integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11093326/restricting-jtextfield-input-to-integers)

```
    NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance();
    format.setGroupingUsed(false);

    NumberFormatter numberFormatter = new NumberFormatter(format);
    numberFormatter.setValueClass(Long.class); 
    numberFormatter.setAllowsInvalid(false); //this is the key

    JFormattedTextField jFormattedTextField = new JFormattedTextField(numberFormatter);
```

Answer (score 0):

It has been some time since I have worked on Swing, but I think you can
create your own Document and set it on the JTextField.

Then in the document object you can control which characters are accepted and rejected as the user types them in.

Here is an example setting a filter on a document:

[Restricting JTextField input to Integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11093326/restricting-jtextfield-input-to-integers)

Answer (score 0):

I would use a [`JSpinner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JSpinner.html) configured with a [`JSpinnerNumberModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SpinnerNumberModel.html).  This is specifically designed for integer input, and also gives the benefit of up/down arrow buttons for changing with the mouse.

Comment: I need text box without arrows