# Send A KeyCode when condition is True(java)

Tags: java, swing, keyevent

I am trying to create a JTextfield that only accepts integers.
But for some reason the keycode is not being sent to the application

```
private void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                   
    String s = String.valueOf(evt.getKeyChar());
    try{
        if(!(s.matches("[0-9]+")))
    {
        evt.setKeyCode(KeyEvent.VK_DELETE);
    }
    }catch(Exception e){}
}
```

Comment: You mean the `VK_DELETE` isn't received by the application?

Comment: yes. nothing happens..i checked with System.out.println(s) and in the console i am getting the alphabests only. but the VK_DELETE is not happening

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is one of approach -- you shouldn't be using a KeyListener with a Swing text component. Instead if you want to filter keyboard input correctly with text components such as a JTextField, add a [DocumentFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html) to the JTextField's Document. In the filter, override the 3 methods that it contains -- `insertString(...)`, `remove(...)`, and `replace(...)` -- and only call the super's method if the current text plus the additional text (or minus the deleted text) is valid.

For a complete example (by me), please look at [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11093360/522444) to a similar question.

Another easier option is to use an [InputVerifier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/InputVerifier.html).