# how a textfield can set only to input numbers in net beans?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans-8

I'm doing a project using `NetBeans IDE 8.2.x` I need to a set a `JTextfield` **only to get users number inputs**. Other characters (like letters) which a user inputs should not take as an input. Can I do it? Is there a specific setting for `Textfield` properties to do this?

Comment: Yes, there is one.

Comment: [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11093326/restricting-jtextfield-input-to-integers) might help.

Comment: You should add the `keyword` that relates to the `GUI` technology you are using.

Comment: I am pretty sure this question is a duplicate.