# replace a int from a JTextField

Tags: java

I can not find a way to replace an integer. I intend to take an integer from a text field and replace it. I have not a code, but I will write something to make myself understood.

```
int a = 1500;
JTextField tf = new JTextField();
```

from this JTextField I would like to take the content number and replace int.
Could you help me?

Comment: You may be interested by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11093326/restricting-jtextfield-input-to-integers)

Answer (score 1):

You may get value of `JTextField()` by using `getText()` method and set for the same by using `setText("value")`

```
try
{
    int a = 1500;
    JTextField tf = new JTextField();
    int value = Integer.parseInt(tf.getText());
    if( value > 0){
       jt.setText(String.valueOf(a)); 
    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
 //handle exception here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First check whether `tf` is instantiated and it has a content, then parse the Integer out of the String.

```
if(tf != null && tf.getText().length > 0){
    a = Integer.parseInt(tf.getText());
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. :) Please, mark this answer as solution, if it helped you.

Comment: If you want to check things, then add a Try-catch block around the `parseInt()` method to handle the case the text can't be converted to `int` (for example "aa" can't be converted to an `int`). In this case it throws a `NumberFormatException`