# Having trouble clearing a text field when an improper character is entered

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I am trying to retrieve the values from a JTextField on a keypress to do something if the values are integers and to clear the field if the values are not integers. Every time I try to retrieve the value, I am getting the value entered before that(if I enter 12 I get 1 back then if I enter 123 I get 12 back) and when I try to clear the field on an invalid character everything but the invalid character gets cleared?

```
public void setUpListeners()
{
    JTextField jT [] = myV.getTextFields();

    jT[0].addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){ 
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){
            int id = e.getID();

            if (id == KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED) 
            {
                char c = e.getKeyChar();
                try
                {
                    //check if chars entered are numbers
                    int temp = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(c));
                    String tempS = jT[0].getText();
                    System.out.println(tempS);
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    jT[0].setText("");
                    System.out.println("Not an integer");

                }
            }
        }
   });
 }
```

Comment: Don't use `KeyListener`, see [Restricting JTextField input to Integers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11093326/1048330) for a better implementation using either a `DocumentFilter.` or a `JFormattedTextField`.

Comment: Don't use a text field. `new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(5,0,100,1));` is kinder to the end user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
public static boolean validateNumber(char num){
    return (num >= '0' && num <='9');
}
```

And then use parameter KeyEvent "e":

```
if(!validateNumber(e.getKeyChar()))
    e.consume();
```

And instead of using

```
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){
```

use

```
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
```

I think you will get what you need, I hope I have helped you ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer its working perfect for the invalid characters now but when I type in a valid number  I am still having the issue of it lagging behind?

Comment: I am getting:  java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""                       
for my first character even when it is a number I'm not sure why.

Comment: The Exception you receive seems to me to be the value you entered as empty "" but with the keyreleased it should be fixed

Comment: Ahhh I see why that is now thank you very much for your response again!

Answer (score 0):

*Swing* components use *Model-View-Controller* (MVC) [software] design pattern / architecture. The *model* holds the data. For a `JTextField` the data is the text it displays. The default model for `JTextField` is [PlainDocument](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/text/PlainDocument.html), however `JTextField` code actually refers to the `Document` interface which `PlainDocument` implements.

Look at the code for method `getText()` in class `JTextComponent` (which is the superclass for `JTextField`) and you will see that it retrieves the text from the `Document`.

When you type a key in `JTextField`, the character gets passed to the `Document`. It would appear that your `keyTyped()` method is invoked **before** the character you typed reaches the `Document`, hence when you call `getText()` in your `keyTyped()` method, you're getting all the text apart from the last character you typed.

That's one of the reasons **not** to use a `KeyListener` in order to validate the text entered into a `JTextField`. The correct way is detailed in the question that *tenorsax* provided a link to in his comment to your question.

Apart from [DocumentFilter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html) or [JFormattedTextField](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html) (or even [InputVerifier](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/InputVerifier.html)), you can [add](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JTextField.html#addActionListener(java.awt.event.ActionListener)) an `ActionListener` to `JTextField` which will execute when you hit *Enter* in the `JTextField`. You will find many on-line examples of how to implement each one of these options, including the link provided in *tenorsax* comment.

Comment: Thank you very much this was exactly what I was looking for to help me understand.