# How do I set a textfield to accept numbers and backspace only?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextfield, keylistener

I am trying to create a GUI project and I want my textfield to only accept digits and backspace. I am currently new to Java so I don't have a lot of knowledge about it yet.

Here's my code so far:

```
AgeField = new JTextField();
AgeField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){
   public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
      String value = AgeField.getText();
      int l = value.length();
      if (ke.getKeyChar() >= '0' && ke.getKeyChar() <= '9' && ke.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) {
           AgeField.setEditable(true);
      }
      else {
           AgeField.setEditable(false);
      }
   }
});
```

My current code only accepts digits, however, when the user enters a letter the textfield becomes uneditable and he cannot enter a digit or delete the letter that he entered.

Comment: I suggest either [JFormattedTextField](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) or [DocumentFilter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Restricting JTextField input to Integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11093326/restricting-jtextfield-input-to-integers)

Comment: Also consider using a `JSpinner` with a `SpinnerNumberModel`. It doesn't work exactly as you describe, but the user might prefer it.

Answer (score 0):

You should apply this change:

```
if ((ke.getKeyChar() >= '0' && ke.getKeyChar() <= '9') || (ke.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE))
```

but you can also do better process instead `setEditable(false)`; for example: you can remove last character.

Comment: Actually, you shouldn't use a `KeyListener`. You can still "paste" non-digit characters into the `JTextField`. That's why `DocumentFilter` class exists.