# JTextArea - only digit

Tags: java, swing, numbers, jtextarea

I need `JTextArea`, not `JFormattedTextField`, because I want 3 lines and on each lines one digits, how can I do it?

Answer (score 5):

Extract the `Document` from the `JTextArea`, cast it to a `PlainDocument` and then add a `DocumentFilter` to the `Document`, filtering out all un-allowed input.

Please click this link for the [Document Filter Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter).

For an example of the opposite, a `DocumentFilter` which prevents the user from typing numbers into the document, please see: [Using DocumentFilter.FilterBypass](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9346426/522444). It would be easy to adapt this to your needs.