# what should I do when DocumentFilter not listening for changes?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, documentfilter

Hi I have the following code :

```
      AbstractDocument d = (AbstractDocument)editorText.getDocument();
      d.setDocumentFilter(new myFilter());
```

where editorText is a JTextArea. and my DocumentFiler is defined as follows :

```
private class myFilter extends DocumentFilter{
       public void insertString(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb,
               int offset,
               String string,
               AttributeSet attr){
           System.out.print("insert invoked");
                 try {
                    super.insertString(fb, offset, "; You inserted the string: "+string, attr);
                } catch (BadLocationException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
       }
       public void replace(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb,
               int offset,
               String string,
               AttributeSet attr){
           System.out.print("replace invoked");
             try {
                super.insertString(fb, offset, "; You inserted the string: "+string, attr);
            } catch (BadLocationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
       }
   }
```

I want the code to work as follows: If a character is typed, then what is expected is that insertString function must fire, and what must be seen on the screen is ;you inserted the string: . This is not the case. What should I do to make the program fire on every character pressed and process it and display on screen?

Comment: addept for an  [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), it must be in the case that something basic doesn't works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if you "override" all methods of [DocumentFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html) in the way you need. At least in the method [`replace(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html#replace%28javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter.FilterBypass,%20int,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20javax.swing.text.AttributeSet%29) I noticed that you missed the `int length` parameter. I suggest to change it to:

```
public void replace(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String string, AttributeSet attr){
  System.out.print("replace invoked");
  try {
    super.insertString(fb, offset, "; You inserted the string: "+string, attr);
  } catch (BadLocationException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();                                                                                                                                                            
  }                                                                                                                                                                                   
}
```